# Issue using Java Array

Tags: java, arrays

```
 import java.io.*;

public class Array {
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader
    inpt = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System. in ));

    System.out.println("How many criteria?");//ask for how many records
    int n = Integer.parseInt(inpt.readLine());// store in n

    int[] arrayCrit = new int[n];//create array with size n
    String[] crits = new String[n];

        //**as you mentioned in edit you want to take all the input before printing**      
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
      System.out.print("Criteria: ");
      crits[i] = inpt.readLine();

      System.out.print("Percentage: ");
      arrayCrit[i] = Integer.parseInt(inpt.readLine());      
    }

    System.out.println("How many students' record?");
    int n1 = Integer.parseInt(inpt.readLine());

    int [] arrayCritr = new int [n1];
    String [] arraySname = new String [n1];

    for(int i=0; i<n1; i++){
    String name;
    System.out.print("Student Name: ");
    arraySname[i] = inpt.readLine();
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++){ 
    System.out.print("Grade in "+ crits[i] + ": ");
    arrayCritr[j] = Integer.parseInt(inpt.readLine());
    crits[i]=crits[i+1];
  }
  crits[i]=crits[i-i];
}
}
}
```

- How many criteria? 4
- Criteria: Quiz
- Percentage: 25
- Criteria: Att
- Percentage: 15
- Criteria: Major Exam
- Percentage: 40
- Criteria: Minor Exam
- Percentage: 20
- How many students' record? 2
- Student Name: Wayne
- Grade in Quiz: 90
- Grade in Att: 80
- Grade in Att: 70

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at Array.main(Array.java:41)

Process completed.

(Thanks again to the people who helped me earlier)

Hello again, I encountered another problem for this program. The output above is somewhat wrong. The arrays are not functioning very well. The 3rd Grade name should be Major Exam but somehow it's not moving and it's stuck in there. Also I want to know how to reset the value in order for the 2nd student to input the grades. Once again, I need your help as I'm new to java and I'm learning it. Thank You.

Edit: I need to output something like this..

- How many criteria? 4
- Criteria(1): Quiz
- Percentage: 25
- Criteria(2): Attendance
- Percentage: 25
- Criteria(3): Major Exam
- Percentage: 25
- Criteria(4): Minor Exam
- Percentage 25
- How many students' record? 2
- Student Name(1): Harold
- Grade in Quiz: 90
- Grade in Attendance: 85
- Grade in Major Exam: 95
- Grade in Minor Exam: 89
- Student Name(2): Jane
- Grade in Quiz: 80
- Grade in Attendance: 75
- Grade in Major Exam: 87
- Grade in Minor Exam: 93

This is exactly what I need to display.. am I asking for an impossible thing to do?

Comment: What are you trying to do in the line `crits[i]=crits[i-i];`? It makes no sense. Is there a typo there?

Comment: You cannot open a new topic starting from "the middle of the story" ...

Comment: do each student will have multiple score or single score?

Comment: @Floris I'm trying to reset the value so that the 2nd student will start in with "Grade in Quiz" rather than continuing with the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are messing up your `Crits` array in the line `crits[i]` = crits[i+1];`

Soon, all the criteria will be overwritten with the last one. You already start to see that in your first bit of output:

```
Student Name: Wayne
Grade in Quiz: 90
Grade in Att: 80
Grade in Att: 70
```

But really, you need to get straight in your head what each array means, what each loop counter means. It is helpful to do this with pseudo code:

```
get number of criteria

get each criteria as input

get number of students

for each student in students:
  output student name
  for each c in criteria:
    output criteria for this student
```

When you look at your code, you will find that your structure doesn't follow this very well. Don't change the criteria array - change only where you are pointing in the array (i.e., the index).

In this context, it is helpful to use more meaningful variable names: `numStudents` and `numCriteria`, and `studentIndex` and `criteriaIndex` instead of `n, n1, i, j`. Once you do that, things will clean up and the problem will become apparent.

Answer (score 2):

you iterate from 0 to `n` on `arrayCritr`, but you initialize `arrayCritr` with `n1`, both of which come from user input.

if `n` is ever bigger than `n1` than you'll get that exception.

in your case, `n` is 4, and `n1` should be 2, so you'll get an exception.

---

either change your for loop to use `n1`

```
for(int j=0; j<n1; j++){
```

or initialize `arrayCritr` with `n`

```
int [] arrayCritr = new int [n];
```

Comment: I tried doing this, but it's still not moving..
The reason why I put for(int j=0; j<n1; j++){ is because I need to input the 4 criteria in the grades loop with its value.

Answer (score 0):

That line near the end:

```
for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
```

Shouldn't it be

```
for(int j=0; j<n1; j++){
```

You are using the wrong array limit.

Answer (score 0):

Your arrayCritr is of n1 size but you are using index  from 0 to n. When your n > n1 then you will have this error. Change following code:

arrayCritr[j] = Integer.parseInt(inpt.readLine());

to

arrayCritr[i] = Integer.parseInt(inpt.readLine());

also having arrayCritr in your nested loop does not have sense so you better move it higher.